# Add a line in between a SQL table and change following id

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I would like to insert a row in the middle of my SQL table. Similar to Excel, the existing rows should then be automatically increased by ID+1. Is there such a function?

Example:

Current state:

[image]

After insert inbetween:

[image]

Comment: No there is no function. You have to update the rows after the row where you add it

Comment: *I would like to insert a row in the middle of my SQL table.* The table is unordered heap, there is no "first"-"last"-"in the middle" until ORDER BY specified in SELECT query. Your question makes no sense. And altering the primary key value is one of the worst practices.

Comment: There is no "middle" row or "first" row or "last" row in a table; a table is a *set* of rows. Your ID column has values that enable you to specify a criteria by which to order your data by, if you need a new row to have a specific ordinal position you need to amend the data as appropriate.

Comment: Never, ever change Id's. You will mess up foreign keys etc.

Comment: Looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1):

Please never do it in production.

Setup

```
create table tbl(
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,  
  val varchar(20)  

  );
insert into tbl (val)
values
('a'),('b'),('c'),('d');
```

The script to add 'x' between 'b' and 'c' when ordered by `id`

```
update tbl
   set id=id+1
where id > 2
order by id desc;

insert tbl(id, val)
values (3,'x');
```

Comment: OK understood, looks like a workaround. Thank you

Comment: @MischaMustermann Workaround? No, it isn't, it's how SQL works. But, as said, changing the PK to reflect order is a strange thing. Are you sure you don't really want an additional column to store the order?

Comment: *`where id > 2`* Where the value `2` have been taken from? a subquery which retrieves `id` for `'b'` is more correct.

Comment: @Akina, it can be as well >= id of 'c' , or it could be a position with no val dependency.